# Why do we always have to inject both ActivatedRouteSnapshot and RouterStateSnapshot in AuthGuard

Tags: angular, routes

I am newbie in Angular 2. On Angular.io Routing tutorial, I see that ActivatedRouteSnapShot and RouterStateSnapshot always be declared(inject) in AuthGuard function: canActivate, canActivateChild, resolve ....
However, usually just 1 be used. You can see below:

```
canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): boolean {
    let url: string = state.url;

    return this.checkLogin(url);
  }
resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Promise<Crisis> {
    let id = route.params['id'];

    return this.cs.getCrisis(id).then(crisis => {
      if (crisis) {
        return crisis;
      } else { // id not found
        this.router.navigate(['/crisis-center']);
        return null;
      }
    });
  }
```

So why do always need to inject both?

Answer (score 4):

The `canActivate` method has these parameters because you implement the [CanActivate](https://angular.io/api/router/CanActivate) Interface, which is a so called Guard.

```
canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean;
```

So independently from the fact whether you need it or not, you have it, they will be provided by Angular when it calls the method.

For the `resolve` method, the situation is the same, you implement the [Resolve](https://angular.io/api/router/Resolve) Interface, where you have to implement the resolve method:

```
resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<T> | Promise<T> | T;
```

An interface is a contract and therefore non-negotiable.